# Stacked time series plot in python

Tags: python, visualization, pandas, seaborn

In pandas I can set the date as index, and then run `df.plot()` to see a line chart. How do I make that line chart **stacked** as in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Add your sample df

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use

```
df.plot.area()
```

Found [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/254-pandas-stacked-area-chart/) after a quick google search.

Comment: Np. The keyword you may have left out was “area”, but honestly I’m not sure how I remembered that’s what these plots are called.

Comment: Do you know how I would do if I would add a group D to that plot from python-graph-gallery, and group D should *not* be stacked i.e. just a regular line?

Comment: df.plot.area() returns the matplotlib axis object, just call ax.plot(my_data)